# Turning String of Length X -> Length Y

Tags: python, string

I have two strings in variables x and y, where the length of x is greater than the length of y. How can you map the smaller string (y) to the size of the large string (x)?

For example:

```
x = "appleappleapple" # (length 15)
y = "abc" # (length 3) This should be mapped to "abcabcabcabcabc"

while len(y) < len(x):
    y+=y
while len(y) > len(x):
    y = y[:-1] 

print x 
print y 

appleappleapple
abcabcabcabcabc
```

Is there a very pythonic/efficient way to do this operation?

Comment: sorry. will close the question.

Answer (score 4):

```
x = "appleappleapple" # (length 15)
y = "abc" # (length 3) This should be mapped to "abcabcabcabcabc"
z = (y*(len(x)/len(y)+1))[:len(x)]
```